# How to fix JpaRepository error in Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create an interface that extends the JpaRepository. Though when I extend the class it underlines it in a red line which means its an error. I tried imported the contents using `import org.springframework.data.*;` but it still would not work.

**Code:**

```
package com.Holden.db;

import com.Holden.model.*;
import org.springframework.boot.*;

public interface AppRepository extends JpaRepository<AppService, String> {


}
```

I have tried:

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.data.*;
```

Pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Environment:

```
Eclipse Photon
```

Comment: The `JpaRepository` isn't in the `org.springframework.data` but a sub package. Use your IDE to fix the error (alt + enter or alt + 1 IIRC are your friends).

Comment: Press `ctrl+shift+o` to automatically fix all imports (BTW the JpaRepository is in `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository`)

Comment: @helospark It still does not work, even when I use ```ctrl+shift+o``` or ```alt+enter```. I try to import ```org.springframework.data``` but it gives an error. I only see that I have the ability to import ```org.springframework.boot```

Comment: @kane_003 Click on your pom.xml, then to `dependency hierarchy` tab, do you see spring-data-jpa dependency (you can use the filter in the top)?

Comment: My guess is that one of your jar is corrupt. (Eclipse had an issue with that back in the day: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=534228). Removing your .m2 folder and letting Eclipse download the jars again will solve the issue (and also update your version).
You can also try alt+F5 to update your Maven project (maybe it is not up-to-date).
BTW you need this import `import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;`, but I guess, it will be also cause error.
Can you build your application using Maven command line (if you add the above import)?

Comment: @helospark No, I don't see ```spring-data-jpa``` in the filter but it doesn't make sense because in my ```pom.xml``` I used the maven ```spring-data-jpa``` dependency and the ```spring-boot-starter-data-jpa``` dependency.

Comment: @helospark When you say delete the ```.m2``` do you mean like delete the whole directory?

Comment: @helospark Thank you, deleting the ```.m2``` directory solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just import the whole class

Like 
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository